# How to mock numpy.fromfile?

Tags: python, unit-testing, numpy, mocking

I'm trying to pass `numpy.fromfile` a mocked `file`, and I keep getting the following error:

> IOError: !first argument must be an open file

Here's a basic example, using `mock_open` taken from the [Further Example](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#mocking-open) section of mock package:

```
import numpy as np
from mock import MagicMock, patch

file_spec = file

def mock_open(mock=None, data=None):
    if mock is None:
        mock = MagicMock(spec=file_spec)

    handle = MagicMock(spec=file_spec)
    handle.write.return_value = None
    if data is None:
        handle.__enter__.return_value = handle
    else:
        handle.__enter__.return_value = data
    mock.return_value = handle
    return mock


if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = mock_open()
    with patch('__main__.open', m, create=True):
        with open('foo', 'rb') as h:
            print h.mock_calls
            try:
                result = np.fromfile(h)
            except IOError:
                print "io error!"
                print h.mock_calls
```

resulting in:

```
% [call.__enter__()] 
% io error!
% [call.__enter__()]
```

I could just mock `numpy.fromfile`, and that's probably what I'll end up doing. I had trouble understanding the follow

1. why the above example does not work
2. why I have trouble debugging `fromfile` (by calling `pdb.set_trace()` just before `fromfile` and stepping into `fromfile`. The debugger seems to step over the call no matter what.
3. why I can't find `fromfile` in the `numpy` source code. Such a function exists in `numpy/numarray/functions.py`, `numpy/core/records.py` and `numpy/ma/core.py`, but none of these raise an error as the one listed above.

Any help clarifying the above issues is much appreciated. I'm using `numpy` version 1.6.1 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your mocked open() isn't working, but since you are immediately calling your own mock, you have a simpler option:  create a file with `StringIO`, and hand that to numpy.fromfile.

Questions 2 and 3 are probably due to numpy.fromfile being written in C.

Comment: I've tried using StringIO and it doesn't work. Your right that `fromfile` is written in C, and I'm pretty sure it's `array_fromfile` found in `numpy/core/src/multiarry/multiarraymodule.c`. This method calls `npy_PyFile_Dup(file, 'rb')` which looks for a file number using `PyObject_AsFileDescriptor`, and `StringIO` has no `fileno()` method... it's not clear if this is why it's failing, but it's my guess so far....